# MySQL First row in 15 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want first record in 15 minutes interval.

I have a MySQL table which has datetime rows with ~1min interval, I want to retrieve the first record and after that again the first record within the next 15 min. I am confused whether to use join or MySQL variable or nested query. Even if you dont know right guide me what should I use variables or join or nested ?

To be specific we have a table with one column date_timestamp as

```
+---------------------+
|   date_timestamp    |
+---------------------+
| 2014-01-07 11:49:42 |
| 2014-01-07 11:50:12 |
| 2014-01-07 11:50:31 |
| 2014-01-07 11:50:42 |
| 2014-01-07 11:51:22 |
| 2014-01-07 11:51:42 |
| 2014-01-07 11:52:52 |
| 2014-01-07 11:53:12 |
| 2014-01-07 11:53:32 |
| 2014-01-07 11:54:22 |
| 2014-01-07 11:55:42 |
| 2014-01-07 11:58:02 |
| 2014-01-07 11:59:22 |
| 2014-01-07 12:00:02 |
| 2014-01-07 12:00:42 |
| 2014-01-07 12:01:32 |
| 2014-01-07 12:01:52 |
| 2014-01-07 12:02:22 |
| 2014-01-07 12:03:42 |
| 2014-01-07 12:04:42 |
| 2014-01-07 12:05:02 |
+---------------------+

i want the output to be if i select 5 minute interval 
+---------------------+
|   date_timestamp    |
+---------------------+
| 2014-01-07 11:49:42 |
| 2014-01-07 11:54:22 |
| 2014-01-07 11:59:22 |
| 2014-01-07 12:04:42 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: You could convert it to unix_timestamp and divide by 15, floor it, then group by it?

Comment: if you paste your code here..

Comment: How do you mean by first record? Is it the in the asc order of datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE (adjusted to meet your sample data and to ignore seconds):**

```
select date_timestamp from (
select 
date_timestamp
, if(date_format(date_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') = @a, 1, 0) as equals
, if(date_format(date_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') = @a, @a:=@a + interval 5 minute, @a) as mya
from my_table, 
(select @a := (select date_format(min(date_timestamp), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') from my_table)) var_init 
order by date_timestamp
) sq
where equals = 1;
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd4cf/3/0)</kbd>

**Original answer:**

I would use user defined variables.

Test data:

```
create table interv(id int auto_increment primary key, myd datetime);

insert into interv(myd) values 
(now()), 
(now() + interval 7 minute), 
(now() + interval 9 minute), 
(now() + interval 15 minute), 
(now() + interval 16 minute),
(now() + interval 30 minute), 
(now() + interval 35 minute);
```

Query:

```
select id, myd from (
select 
id
, myd
, if(myd = @a, 1, 0) as equals
, if(myd = @a, @a:=@a + interval 15 minute, @a) as mya
from interv, 
(select @a := (select min(myd) from interv)) var_init 
order by myd
) sq
where equals = 1;
```

Result:

```
| ID |                          MYD |
|----|------------------------------|
|  1 | March, 28 2014 09:03:23+0000 |
|  4 | March, 28 2014 09:18:23+0000 |
|  6 | March, 28 2014 09:33:23+0000 |
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/454a0/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for wat a lovely effort in time frame, however i am only getting 8 ~ 10 rows im figuring what might be possible problem.I have 2000 records.

Comment: You will have to be more specific. Based on your sample data it works...

Comment: Yeah it works on the sample data but there are inconsistencies in the table.. how can i clear that any clue ?

Comment: What inconsistencies? I can't help you with this little bit of information....

Answer (score 0):

Not clear with the question,
Still if you are using mYSQL go get the last inseted row

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()";
```

Comment: Everybody knows how to get the row with the latest or earliest date. That's not the question here. And you better read up about last_insert_id() again.